# I want to click to implement the event once, then remove event from the element that clicked

Tags: javascript, events

As in the title of the question.
I have many elements, because I have used `getElementsByTagName('*')`.
Then, I have added a click event on every element, and I have used loop for that.

**See the code:**

**HTML**

```
<div id="box">
    <span class="box"> span</span><br/>
    <span class="box">span 2</span><br/>
    <span class="box">span 3</span><br/>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    len = element.length, result = document.getElementById('result'), i, timer;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    element[i].addEventListener('click', fn = function (e) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        result.style.display = 'inline';
        result.innerHTML = "<pre>" + e.target.innerHTML + "</pre>";
        timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
            result.style.display = 'none';
        }, '2000');
        e.target.removeEventListener('click', fn);
    });
}
```

- I want to when a user clicks on a specific element, implement the
  event once, then removes the event from this element only.
- Also, I want to add the function(callback) name to the `removeEventListener` function automatically, not like this `e.target.removeEventListener('click', fn) //fn is the callback name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the event callback gets called with the context of element, you have added the listener to it, here `this` would point to `element[i]`,so you can change it like:

```
element[i].addEventListener('click', function fn(e) {
    //your stuff
    this.removeEventListener('click', fn);
});
```

note that if you create `fn` function this way, it is kind of private in the function body, we used to use `arguments.callee` which is not a good practice these days, you can not use it in `strict mode`.

---

all I am saying is by the time `strict mode` showed up since:

> The 5th edition of ECMAScript (ES5) forbids use of arguments.callee()
>   in strict mode.

we could do that like this:

```
element[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    //your stuff
    this.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee);
});
```

but the new alternative is using function's label, for instance if you do:

```
var myfunc = function func(){
     //you have access to the current function using func
     //and you can add or remove it to/from something
     someThing.removeEventListener('click', func);
};
//but if you want to do it here you can have it using myfunc
someOtherThing.removeEventListener('click', myfunc);
```

So that's what I mean by:

> kind of private in the function body

you have access to that function in the function body using its label `func`, but out there in the code you don't have it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you please explain more about the meaning this sentence `it is kind of private in the function code`

Comment: @LionKing: I really tried to clarify it, check my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Define function before as a variable. http://jsfiddle.net/m8UgC/

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    len = element.length, result = document.getElementById('result'), i, timer;
var fn = function (e) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        result.style.display = 'inline';
        result.innerHTML = "<pre>" + e.target.innerHTML + "</pre>";
        timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
            result.style.display = 'none';
        }, '2000');
        this.removeEventListener('click', fn);
    }
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    element[i].addEventListener('click', fn);
}
```